# File_get_contents return different result compare to direct url call

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

Hi i am try to get linkedin count for share with php .

code is

```
$url_social = 'https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=' . urlencode(trim($url)) . '&format=json';
$res = file_get_contents($url_social, false, $context);
```

out put of above code i got it

```
Array
(
    [count] => 0
    [fCnt] => 0
    [fCntPlusOne] => 1
    [url] => https://www.botoa.com/contest/detail/40/77/20160428_2
)
```

but sam url i try to direct url in browser with url : https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.botoa.com%2Fcontest%2Fdetail%2F40%2F77%2F20160428_2&format=json

its return result

```
{
count: 8,
fCnt: "8",
fCntPlusOne: "9",
url: "https://www.botoa.com/contest/detail/40/77/20160428_2"
}
```

so different is you can see count in first result 0 and second 8  why ? and what is possible solution

Comment: Logged and not logged in.

Comment: the are the same for me (result 0. I am logged in)

Comment: yes you are right that what is specific solution for this ?